# Rails Forms for custom actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm trying to link the input of a form to a specific action in my rails app.

Currently if I go to `www.myapp.com/check/:idNumber`, I'll be able to trigger the action just fine (which means routes is setup properly?). This action is basically a function call to a ruby/rails script with the parameter "idNumber" being passed to it. If the function is successful, it would return a newly created "Person" object and nil otherwise. This is different than the standard `new` operation as it determines the the attributes based on some information that it obtained from a database somewhere else.

Rake routes does give me the following:

```
   check        /check/:idNumber(.:format)    person#check {:id=>/\d+/}
```

What I'm having trouble implementing is the form itself.

```
<%= form_tag("/check", :method => "get") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:idNumber) %>
<% end %>
```

Controller action:

```
  def check
    regCheck = RegCheck.new  

    @person = regCheck.check_id(params[:idNumber])

    if @person.name == nil
      redirect_to root_path
    end
end
```

submitting the form above would bring me to `myapp.com/check?utf8=✓&idNumber=1234` instead. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you want to submit a "POST" request at "/check/:idNumber" ?

Comment: @Abid Oops, yeah. POST would be more appropriate here but that's probably no the main issue.

Comment: you are providing it the wrong url "/check" when you want to submit to "/check/idNumber" and you are providing the url twice, both in the first argument as "/check" and also in :url, use either one of them and use the correct url

Comment: also It isnt clear if you want to submit the form to /check/id or only /check and send the id as a POST param

Comment: take a look at http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag
specially the last note

Comment: @Abid Ok, I kinda have no idea what I'm doing here. Basically IDNumber is going to be submitted to a `check` action in the controller. The action would in turn call a function that I wrote and pass in the idNumber to the function. If the person if found in the database, the regCheck.check_id function would return the person.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that using the `check_path` helper that is generated from the routes file is your best bet.

The form should look like this then.

```
<%= form_tag(check_path) do %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:idNumber) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Rails forms can be finicky, especially when trying to build really customized forms.

This line 
`= form_for [@object]`

Determines where the form goes, as well as the object that is being implemented. If you want to route the form to a different place, you can user the `:url` option. This options determines the path of the form, however you must keep in mind that the method is determined by the `@object`. If it is a new object, the method will be POST, an existing object will use a PUT method.

Let's suppose you want to update an existing object, but you want to send in data for a new object belonging to the existing object. That would look like

```
= form_for [@object], :as => @child_object, :url => my_optional_custom_path do |f|
    # etc...
```

This generates a form sending a PUT request to the custom url (or the update path for `@object` if no custom url is supplied. The PUT request is sent with the parameter `params[:child_object]`.

Hopefully this helps!

Best,

-Brian

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible the way you're trying.. The URL for the form is created `before` the user inputs any data.. So you need to remove the `:idNumber` from your routing..

If you do you get the following route:

```
check        /check(.:format)    person#check
```

Because the regex is removed now, you need to do this in you're controller:

```
def check

  # Make sure ID is digits only
  idNumber = params[:idNumber].gsub(/[^\d]/, '')

  regCheck = RegCheck.new

  @person = regCheck.check_id(idNumber)

  if @person.name == nil
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

You're form is allright, but you may want to use `check_path` like TheBinaryhood suggests..

If you really want it to be `check/:idNumber` you may also be able to submit the form to another action and redirect it to the right path from there..